# is there any method to create mapping for nao robot by python?

Tags: python, robot, nao-robot, choregraphe

I connect the Nao robot to my Python shell with `naoqi`, it works for some codes, now I want to do mapping for a room by Python, how can I do it without ROS, I do not have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ALNavigation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation.html) it offers the method [explore](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/exploration-api.html?highlight=exploration#ALNavigationProxy::explore__float).

You can find Python script code examples for exploring and localizing [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/exploration-api.html#code-samples).